# GetInt("x").Value doesn't return int while x = 1.0

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I have publish a game and some users had a problem,
it should be int this line since everything above this code work 
`int s = message.Data.GetInt("x").Value;` 
("x" : 1.0) and then the app stops !
I have never encounter this problem while testing my app (even the users says that some times it works, sometimes not)

Answer (score 0):

Check all the places you Set "x", you probably Set it as a float somewhere which adds the ".0".

If your app is crashing, the unstable code could warrant you to wrap it in a try-catch method to handle these errornous crashes.

Also, note that you can specify a default value on GetInt("x", 1) in case it doesn't exist.

Comment: actually i have a JavaScript server that sends a json message to my app (with x value) both var x=1; and var x = parseInt("1")  send 1.0